# servlet not working in CouchBase server

Tags: java, servlets, caching, couchbase

IN order to test couchbase, I am trying to create 30K-specific documents in 15 minutes.

During the test, 6563 documents are created and then hangs. I have seen that it takes 2 minutes to create 0-3K thousand; 5 minutes to create between 3K-6K; and 5 minutes to create the final 6K -6.5K documents.

Example [here](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/java-application-development-using-couchbase/).

I would appreciate help in understanding what I am doing wrong. The code is below:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    private CouchbaseClient client;

    public ConnectionManager() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            logger.info("Opening base connection.");
            List<URI> hosts = Arrays.asList(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools"));

            String bucket = "default";

            String password = "";

            client = new CouchbaseClient(hosts, bucket, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            client = null;
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        logger.info("Closing base connection.");
        if (client != null) {
            client.shutdown();
            client = null;
        }
    }

    public CouchbaseClient getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}



        public class DatabaseManager {
        ConnectionManager cm;

        public DatabaseManager() {
            cm = new ConnectionManager();
        }

        public String addDocument(String result) {
            CouchbaseClient c = cm.getClient();
            JSONParameters j = new JSONParameters();
            String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            Date today = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);

            j.setTime(date);
            j.setData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            j.setSender_id(result);
            j.setFlag(false);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(j);

            c.add(result, json);
            return json;
        }




        public class DataBaseAddServlet extends HttpServlet {

            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
                try {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 30000; k++) {
                        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
                        dbManager.addDocument(id);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    resp.getOutputStream().println(e.getMessage());
                    resp.flushBuffer();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't immediately spot anything.  Did you try the same code outside a servlet?  Also, I think you can probably simplify the use of the Gson object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed a key point from the example you linked to: in the Servlet, DatabaseManager is injected via dependency injection and thus there's only one instance created.

In you code, you actually create a new DatabaseManager inside the loop, so you end up creating 30K CouchbaseClients. You are probably hitting a limit, and definitely wasting a lot of time and resources with that much extra clients.

Just moving the `DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();` before the for loop should make things far better.

Comment: I agree with Simon and just so you know, you should be able to create 30k docs in a few seconds depending on server/network resources and the size of your docs.